# Программа в python выдает отличные выходные данные от данных, который должны были вывестись

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется задание: Напишите программу, ко­то­рая в по­сле­до­ва­тель­но­сти на­ту­раль­ных чисел опре­де­ля­ет ко­ли­че­ство чисел, крат­ных 3. Про­грам­ма по­лу­ча­ет на вход ко­ли­че­ство чисел в последовательности, а затем сами числа. В по­сле­до­ва­тель­но­сти все­гда име­ет­ся число, крат­ное 3. Ко­ли­че­ство чисел не пре­вы­ша­ет 100. Введённые числа не пре­вы­ша­ют 300. Про­грам­ма долж­на вы­ве­сти одно число — ко­ли­че­ство чисел, крат­ных 3.

При вводе чисел из примера выдает на выходе 3, а не 2.
В чем может быть проблема?

[image: Код]

[image: картинка 1]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: г) в заголовке лучше указывать в чем конкретно заключается проблема. Заголовки типа "проблема в python" бессмысленны и никому не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Во входных данных на 3 делятся три числа, а не два. Так что никакой проблемы нет ‍♂️

Comment: Я как понял, в ответе стоит 2 потому что число 24 меньше 26, а стоит оно после 26 . То есть нужно каким-то образом не принимать числа, которые не идут в правильной последовательности

Comment: В описании задачи нет ничего про правильность последовательности.

Answer (score 0):

Решение на скорую руку, по сомнительному условию:

```
user = int(input('Введите количество чисел: '))
cnt = 0
last_number = None
numbers = [int(input('Введите {} число: '.format(str(i + 1)))) for i in range(user)]

for number in numbers:
    if last_number is None:
        last_number = number

    if number >= last_number and not number % 3:
        cnt += 1
        last_number = number

    if number < last_number:
        break

print(cnt)
```